# font size style not applying on anchor as fontawsome

Tags: css

I have to use icon with anchor, color property working in style but font-size not working, I have added the code below including div's as wrapper, please see the code below and guide me accordingly.

HTML

```
<div class="tab">
  div class="tabBtn">
    <button class="tablinks" rel="a" >
       <a class="fas fa-edit anchor_icon" href="#"></a>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.tab {
width:60px;
height:auto;
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
right: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #fff;
}
div.tabBtn{
display: block;
position: relative;
width:50px;
height: auto;
}

.tabBtn button {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(255,0,0,.6);
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
 }

 .anchor_icon{
   color: black;
   font-size: 52 !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably just missed it but you are missing px

```
 .anchor_icon{
   color: black;
   font-size: 52 !important;
  }
```

just add px or any othore kind of unit to your `52 !important`
so it would look like this

```
.anchor_icon{
   color: black;
   font-size: 52px !important;
  }
```

Comment: @Helenesh sorry, was busy with writing the post and then i saw yours after posting it

Comment: @Helenesh in all the cases we shouldn't answer such question, we should vote to close as *typo issue*

Answer (score 0):

You should set the font-size to px , em or a percent of the parent element's font size(%)